# How would I filter an array of objects by : If id numbers are consecutive

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JSON file that has an array of objects with data inside :

```json
[
    {
    "_id": "62bd5fba34a8f1c90303055c",
    "index": 0,
    "email": "mcdonaldholden@xerex.com",
    "nameList": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Wendi Mooney"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Holloway Whitehead"
      }
    ]
    },
    {
    "_id": "62bd5fbac3e5a4fca5e85e81",
    "index": 1,
    "nameList": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Janine Barrett"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Odonnell Savage"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Patty Owen"
      }
    ]
    }, ...
```

My job is to filter the arrays that have more than two names and if their id are consecutive.
I managed to sort users with more than two `user.name` but cant grasp the concept of filtering consecutive id numbers

```
let lister3 = userData.filter(names => names?.nameList?.filter(name => name?.name).length > 2)
```

Which returns me the objects with more than two user names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` takes a function that returns `true` if you want to retain the item or `false` if not. In this function, you could check the length of the `nameList`, and then iterate over its members and make sure their `id`s are consecutive:

```js
retult = userData.filter(u => {
    if (u.nameList.length < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < u.nameList.length; ++i) {
        if (u.nameList[i].id != u.nameList[i - 1].id + 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

a item  should need tow  conditions,one is nameList length is two ,the other is the itemId of  nameList  is consecutive;
so first as you do :

```
`
let lister3 = userData.filter(names => names?.nameList?.filter(name => name?.name).length > 2)
`
```

;
then
`

```
let lister4 =  lister3.filter(names=>{
let idOfStr = names.nameList?.sort((a,b)=>a.id-b.id).map(item=>item.id).join("");
let resultStr = Array.from(idOfStr.length).fill(+idOfStr[0]).map((item,index)=>+item+index).join('');
return idOfStr === resultStr
})
```

`

hope this is useful for you